# How to increase transition speed in Navigator - React Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I'm using Navigator component to transition from one scene to another scene. Is there any way to increase the transition speed? I have used SceneConfigs but I need the animation a bit more faster. Is there any way to increase that?

It turns out that I can play with some properties of sceneConfig by doing this:

```
sceneConfig: Object.assign({}, Navigator.SceneConfigs.FloatFromBottomAndroid, {
  defaultTransitionVelocity: 3,
  springFriction: 20,
  springTension: 300,
}),
```

But this only applies to when I come out of the scene, not when I enter into the scene!